# Matching but ignoring nested parentheses with JISON

Tags: javascript, parsing, jison

I'm working on a grammar for a templating system. I've hit a snag in the build and I can't quite figure out how to solve this issue. I've simplified down the test case to best emphasize exactly what I'm doing.

Example Strings:

- `(foo)` - works
- `(foo())` - fails `Expecting 'parenEnd', got 'parenInterior'`
- `foo (foo) bar`
- `foo (foo(function() { console.log('stuff'); })) bar`
- `foo (foo.bar.baz("stuff")) bar`

The rules are that within a parenthetical, anything goes, any characters. I don't need to validate, and I don't need to ensure they match a proper format. On the other hand, from my understanding, in order for the parser to function I do need keep track of opening and closing `(` and `)` otherwise the lexer can't know where one parenthetical statement begins and another ends, such as `(foo()) (bar)`. In order to keep track of that I'm using a `paren` start condition which increments a value whenever a paren is hit inside a paren statement, and removes it when a close paren is it.

The problem is it's just not working. The main culprit is it never appears to hit my `<paren>")"` rule and yet I'm hitting the `<paren>"("` rule just fine. They appear syntactically the same, why is one working and the other not?

Grammar

```
%lex

%x paren

%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
<INITIAL>"("         { this.begin("paren"); parenCount = 1; return "parenStart"; };
<paren>"("            { console.log("parenStart", parenCount); parenCount++; return "parenInterior"; };
<paren>")"            { console.log("parenEnd", parenCount); parenCount--; if (parenCount === 0) { this.popState(); return "parenEnd"; } else { return "parenInterior"; } };
<paren>[^\)\(]+       { console.log(this); return "parenInterior"; };
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF';
.                     return 'INVALID';

/lex

%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */

expressions
    : parenStart parenInterior parenEnd { return $1 + $2 + $3; }
    ;

%%

parenCount = 0;
```

Comment: I don't know any more about JISON than I can glean from reading this, so I may be wrong. When you said "fails `Expecting 'parenEnd', got 'parenInterior'`", how did it know what to expect? Was it expecting the outputs to be `parenStart`, `parenInterior`, `parenEnd`, as in `expressions`? If I've read it right, the actual output from `(foo())` would be `parenStart`, `parenInterior`, `parenInterior`, `parenInterior`, `parenEnd`. So it behaves as expected until the 3rd output, which is `parenInterior` when `parenEnd` was expected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are correct, but how do I correct it? Earlier I tried a `parenInteriors : parenInteriors parenInterior | parenInterior` rule, but then it choked at the very beginning. Does that make any sense? You can test grammars online at http://zaach.github.io/jison/try/ and copy and paste my rules in if it's any help.

Comment: I think Louis's answer is about as close as we can get without more clarity about the question. You say "The rules are that within a parenthetical, anything goes, any characters.", and you say the brackets must match, but I don't think you've given any more information. For example, strings with two non-nested pairs of brackets such as `()()`, or with no brackets at all, would fail under that answer; this may not be what you wanted.

Comment: Also, if you want to make sure the curly brackets are also paired off while avoiding strings such as `({)}`, an integer-valued variable `paren` isn't enough. You'll need to replace it with a stack (or array) of bracket symbols, each of which can be `(` or `{`. When you encounter an opening bracket, push it to the stack; when you get a closing bracket, pop one off the stack and make sure it matches the one you just found in the string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that your grammar is not accepting a *sequence* of tokens. If I change you grammar to this, then I get something that can handle the strings you've shown in your question:

```
%lex

%x paren

%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
<INITIAL>"("         { this.begin("paren"); parenCount = 1; return "parenStart"; };
<paren>"("            { console.log("parenStart", parenCount); parenCount++; return "parenInterior"; };
<paren>")"            { console.log("parenEnd", parenCount); parenCount--; if (parenCount === 0) { this.popState(); return "parenEnd"; } else { return "parenInterior"; } };
<paren>[^\)\(]+       { console.log(this); return "parenInterior"; };
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF';
.                     return 'WHATEVER';

/lex

%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */

expressions
    : whateverSeq parenStart parenInteriorSeq parenEnd whateverSeq EOF { return $1 + $2 + $3 + $4 + $5; }
    ;

parenInteriorSeq
    : parenInterior 
    | parenInteriorSeq parenInterior -> $1.concat($2)
    ;

whateverSeq
    : -> ""      // Empty sequence.
    | whatevers  // One or more WHATEVER tokens.
    ;

whatevers
    : whatever
    | whateverSeq WHATEVER -> $1.concat($2)
    ;

%%

parenCount = 0;
```

Then there's no problem with nesting parentheses.

Salient changes:

1. Replaced `INVALID` with `WHATEVER`. Added the rules to have a sequence of `WHATEVER` tokens at the start and end. This allows to have things like `blah (foo) blah`.
2. Replaced `parenInterior` with `parenInteriorSeq` so that you can have sequence of `parenInterior` tokens inside parentheses. This is necessary because in a string like `(foo())`, `foo` is one token, the next `(` is another token and the next `)` is another token. So you have to accept a list of tokens.